# jQuery seems to undo css webkit hover effect

Tags: jquery, css

I have several divs with the class .note and the following css code for them:

```
    .note{
            background: #eff9ff;
            -webkit-transition: background .5s;
        }

            .note:hover{
                background: #d6e4f2;
            }

            .note:active{
                background: #bfcdda;
            }
```

Due to the webkit animation, it will change colors smoothly after hovering over the div.

However, I also use jQuery to change the background of the div completely depending on the attribute 'selectednote' once it is clicked, and only undo that once it is clicked again, like so:

```
$('.note').click(function(){
if($(this).attr('selectednote')=='no'){
    $(this).attr('selectednote','yes');
    $(this).css('background','#bfcdda');
}else if($(this).attr('selectednote')=='yes'){
    $(this).attr('selectednote','no');
    $(this).css('background','#eff9ff');
}
});
```

Everything works fine, but as soon as I click the div and it has changed its background, the css hover and active effects don't work anymore.

Maybe I should get rid of css for that completely? I have tried to come up with the following jQuery for the hovering effect, but to no avail:

```
$('.note').mouseover(function(){
$(this).animate({
    background: '#d6e4f2'
},500);
});
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stick using CSS for this without using invalid custom attributes like that one.

```
.note.selected {
  background: #bfcdda;
}​
```

A simple toggle of  the class `selected`. You can tweak this using `.data()` also.

```
$('.note').click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass("selected");
});​
```

[See it working](http://jsfiddle.net/hDMNC/).

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you very much! Just out of curiosity, do you maybe know what I did wrong with the animate() function? I won't use it anymore, but am just interested.

Comment: @Charles - .animate() doesn't work on colours unless you've included jQueryUI.

Comment: @Charles, you need [jquery-color](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color) to handle those transitions, if i recall correctly. Plus, no need of jQuery UI.

Comment: @Alexander - jQuery UI does colour animations, but also does a lot of other things, so yes: jQuery-color might be a better choice if those other things aren't needed.

Answer (score 2):

I've added `!important` to the `:hover` rule and that seems to fix it.

```
.note:hover{
    background: #d6e4f2 !important;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/heSup/)

Comment: Thank you! However, @Alexander's answer seems to fit best.